# Counting Avg Number of Words Per Sentence

Tags: python, math, split, nlp, counting

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to count the number of words per sentence. For my case, I'm assuming sentences only end with either `"!"`, `"?"`, or `"."`

I have a list that looks like this:

```
["Hey, "!", "How", "are", "you", "?", "I", "would", "like", "a", "sandwich", "."]
```

For the example above, the calculation would be `1 + 3 + 5 / 3`. I'm having a hard time achieving this, though! Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

```
words = ["Hey", "!", "How", "are", "you", "?", "I", "would", "like", "a", "sandwich", "."]

sentences = [[]]
ends = set(".?!")
for word in words:
    if word in ends: sentences.append([])
    else: sentences[-1].append(word)

if sentences[0]:
    if not sentences[-1]: sentences.pop()
    print("average sentence length:", sum(len(s) for s in sentences)/len(sentences))
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution:

```
mylist = ["Hey", "!", "How", "are", "you", "?", "I", "would", "like", "a", "sandwich", "."]
terminals = set([".", "?", "!"]) # sets are efficient for "membership" tests
terminal_count = 0

for item in mylist:
    if item in terminals: # here is our membership test
        terminal_count += 1

avg = (len(mylist) - terminal_count)  / float(terminal_count)
```

This assumes you only care about getting the average, not the individual counts per sentence.

If you'd like to get a little fancy, you can replace the `for` loop with something like this:

```
terminal_count = sum(1 for item in mylist if item in terminals)
```

Comment: That's pretty clever. It would be a bit better to store the terminals in a `set` before the loop. Or if you think that's overkill, then you could at least write the condition simpler as `if item in ".!?"`

Comment: @janos Good call on pulling the terminals out into their own constant. I'd prefer a list over a string, for clarity's sake.

Comment: Why a `list` why not a `set`?

Comment: @jonas You've educated me! I'm reading that sets are much more efficient when finding `x in y`, so I'll update accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Short solution using [re.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) and [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#sum) functions:

```
import re
s = "Hey ! How are you ? I would like a sandwich ."
parts = [len(l.split()) for l in re.split(r'[?!.]', s) if l.strip()]

print(sum(parts)/len(parts))
```

The output:

```
3.0
```

---

In case if there could be only a list of words as input:

```
import re
s = ["Hey", "!", "How", "are", "you", "?", "I", "would", "like", "a", "sandwich", "."]
parts = [len(l.split()) for l in re.split(r'[?!.]', ' '.join(s)) if l.strip()]

print(sum(parts)/len(parts))   # 3.0
```

Comment: The second one worked really well! I like the use of regular expressions, as I'm working on an NLP project of sorts.